# How to change file permissions - Windows XP Home Edition

Tags: windows, windows-xp, security, permissions, file-permissions

I have an executable file that I want to run on my PC. I am running Windows XP Home Edition SP3. When I try to run it, I get a popup saying that access is denied and that I might not have the appropriate permissions. Since there isn't a security tab in file properties on Windows XP I didn't know what to do. I did some research and I found out that you could make the security tab visible by un-selecting "simple file sharing" in the folder view options. Then I found out that only Windows XP Professional Edition has this option. I am wondering if there is any other way to change file permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows XP Home edition by default does not have the security tabs that allows users to configure and change the permissions and rights for Windows folders and drives.

In Windows XP Home Edition you need to Enable and Display Security Tab

To use the Security Tab in Windows XP Home edition operating system, Security Configuration Manager Tool needs to be used. Security Configuration Manager Tool is a tool set to configure security for a Windows NT-based or Windows 2000-based computer. Proceed like this:

- Download Security Configuration Manager Tool (x86 is SCESP4I.EXE) from Microsoft.
- Double click the SCESP4I.EXE and extract the contents to a folder on your hard disk. Go to the folder where the SCESP4I.exe contents are extracted, locate the Setup.inf (Setup Information) file.
- Right click on Setup.inf and select Install and reboot computer after installation finished.
- You can now see the security tab when you view the properties for the drive, file or folder.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer of Overmind is informative and almost complete, the one thing that was missing for me, was a download link.

It seems that, since Microsoft stopped supporting Windows XP, everything related to Windows XP might have been removed from the Microsoft website. I had some trouble locating the package I needed.

Some Googling brought me to [BleepingComputer.com](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/281059/how-to-add-security-tab-in-windows-xp-home/) where I found the required file [scesp4i.exe](ftp://ftp.dataforce.net/pub/support/WinNT4/Secure/scesp4i.exe) (note that this site does not appear to be affiliated to Microsoft, so **download at your own risk** and only if you deem this source trustworthy).

To me, this was the solution. Installing the files in this package allowed me to change the security settings for files on Windows XP Home.